# How to add a style to a {{ form_label(form.name) }}

Tags: twig, symfony

I'm using Symfony 3.0, in this moment I have this code:

```
{{ form_label(form.name, 'Name of the card', { 'attr': {'style': 'color:white'}}) }}
```

Thank you :) !

Comment: Attributes should be set from the form builder not the twig, share your form builder code and i can help you with it

Answer (score 2):

You need to use label_attr for labels, attr is for the widget function.

```
{{ form_label(form.name, 'Name of the card', { 'label_attr': {'style': 'color:white'}}) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand) rendering form row involves three functions
`{{ form_label(form.name) }}
{{ form_errors(form.name) }}
{{ form_widget(form.name) }}`

You can replace form_label(form.name) with your layout

```
<div class="form_label">Name of the card</div> 
<div class ="form_errors">{{ form_errors(form.name) }}</div> 
{{ form_widget(form.name) }}
```